# Конвертировать xls в xlsx Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Доброго времени суток. У меня на текущий момент реализована конвертация из формата xls в xlsx с помощью библиотеки win32com, но мне необходимо избежать такой конвертации, чтобы не использовать эту библиотеку. Как конвертировать xls в xlsx в Python 3? Все найденные мною способы работают только на Python 2 и при изменении кода под Python 3 перестаёт работать.

Comment: Почему не хотите win32com использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного (очень немного) переделал код из ответа на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx) вопрос, чтобы он заработал в python3, однако он переносит только данные, а форматирование, цвета и т.д. - нет, под это надо писать дополнительную логику. Тем не менее, полагаю, что как отправная точка будет то, что надо.

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook


def open_xls_as_xlsx(filename):
    # first open using xlrd
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    index = 0
    nrows, ncols = 0, 0
    while nrows * ncols == 0:
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(index)
        nrows = sheet.nrows
        ncols = sheet.ncols
        index += 1

    # prepare a xlsx sheet
    book1 = Workbook()
    sheet1 = book1.get_active_sheet()

    for row in range(1, nrows):
        for col in range(1, ncols):
            sheet1.cell(row=row, column=col).value = sheet.cell_value(row, col)

    return book1


open_xls_as_xlsx('path_to_file').save('path_to_file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, чтобы не париться с зависимостями библиотек:
https://products.aspose.com/cells/ru/python-java/conversion/xls-to-xlsx/

```
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook

Workbook("input.xls");
workbook.Save("Output.xlsx");

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Comment: вообще, если вопросы идентичны, то стоит не давать один и тот же ответ на оба, а заявить один из вопросов дубликатом второго. это я по поводу [вашего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096874/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-xlsx-%d0%b2-xls/1503442#1503442).