# Сохранение полученного в post запросе Excel в python

Tags: python, excel, post, requests

Есть задача по выгрузке xls файла с рабочего сайта.
Посмотрев что делает браузер - отправляю post запрос. Браузер в ответ на запрос сохраняет файл.

Нужно точно так же сохранить полученный xls файл в xlsx с переименованием.
Пробовал так:

```
response = session.post(base_url, data=data)
with open('ex.xlsx', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Также вместо response.content пробовал response.text, предварительно поменяв с режим записи с wb на w. Результата это не дало. Погуглив документацию по библиотекам для работы с Ecxel - полезного для задачи не нашел.

Может кто уже сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Так конвертните xls в xlsx https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604193/Конвертировать-xls-в-xlsx-python-3

Answer (score 1):

Я так и не понял, почему, но в таком виде сохранение отработало(до этого xls сохранялся битый):

```
response = session.post(base_url, data=data)

output = open('test.xls', 'wb')
output.write(response.content)
output.close()
```

С конвертацией в xlsx также разобрался по ссылке в комментариях.