# Конвертация .XLSX в .XLS

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlsx

У меня скрипт для обработки XLS, но некоторые прайсы приходят в XLSX. Из них нужны только строки и числа, никаких формул не нужно. Попробовал пару решений - вроде бы переводит в файл с типом .xls, но программа на него ругается как на .xlsx.

Вот код, сделано [как тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775285/convert-xlsx-to-xls-and-preserve-hidden-rows):

```
$ pip install pyexcel-xlsx
```

```py
import pyexcel as p

for name in os.listdir(".\\prices"):
    if name.endswith('.xlsx'):
        p.save_book_as(file_name=".\\prices\\"+name, 
               library='pyexcel-xlsx',  # <--- note 1
               skip_hidden_row_and_column=True,  # <--- note 2
               dest_file_name=".\\prices\\"+ (name.replace(".xlsx",".xls")))
        os.remove(".\\prices\\"+name)
```

Comment: ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ: EXCEL в системе не установлен и не может быть установлен!

Comment: ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ2: Вообще он ругается на formatting_info=True. Без него вроде продолжает работать, но дальше я не тестил. И не нужен он?

Comment: Если нужны только значения ячеек, то formatting можно отключить. Т.е. отключатся стили xlsx. Файл станет визуально стрёмным, но значения останутся. Можете также попробовать библиотеку xlrd - она простая, читает и xls, и xlsx.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конвертировать xls в xlsx Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604193/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-xls-%d0%b2-xlsx-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#excel-files):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

filename = "/path/to/file.xlsx"
pd.read_excel(filename).to_excel(filename[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, чтобы не париться с зависимостями библиотек:
https://products.aspose.com/cells/ru/python-java/conversion/xls-to-xlsx/

```
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook

Workbook("input.xls");
workbook.Save("Output.xlsx");

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Comment: вообще, если вопросы идентичны, то стоит не давать один и тот же ответ на оба, а заявить один из вопросов дубликатом второго. это я по поводу [вашего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1503439/178576)