# Загрузка excel файла по ссылке, и конвертировать в xlsx

Tags: python, requests, openpyxl, xlrd

Как, с помощью python, можно открыть excel файл в формате xls по ссылке https://aparat.ua/cli/out.xls, а затем этот же файл конвертировать в формат xlsx, что бы дальше работать с ним с помощью библиотеки openpyxl.

Comment: pandas читает и сохраняет и старый и новый формат екселя

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653192/pandas-xls-to-xlsx-converter

Comment: Ответил тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604193/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-xls-%d0%b2-xlsx-python-3